# Increase score required to finish each new level in my shooter game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning C# and unity and have a basic 2D shooter game I am programming. As can be seen below, I have a score of 3 needed to go to the next scene (or level) of my game, and then the score resets. How can I make it so that for the second level you need 3 points, the 3rd level you need 5 points, then 7 etc. instead of 3 points for every level?

```
public class Pickups : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text scoreText;

    private void Start()
    {
        Scoring.totalScore = 0;
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + Scoring.totalScore;
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        if(Scoring.totalScore>=3)
        {
           int currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneIndex +1);
            Scoring.totalScore = 0; 
        }
    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) 
    {
        if (collision.tag == "Gem")
        {
            Scoring.totalScore++;
            AudioManager.instance.PlaySfx(1);

            scoreText.text = "Score: " + Scoring.totalScore;
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the pattern, for a current scene `currentSceneIndex`, you have to match the score to `currentSceneIndex * 2 - 1`.

```cs
private void Update()
{
    if(Scoring.totalScore >= currentSceneIndex * 2 - 1)
    {
        # rest of the code
    }

    # rest of the code
}
```

Comment: also don't poll check this in `Update` .. do it event driven there where you actually change the value right after `Scoring.totalScore++;`